# Windows Search in Taskbar with my own results

Tags: c#, .net, windows, search, taskbar

I want to provide a custom Search Connector for Windows Search without accessing a php or aspx website. Is this possible? I don't find anything.
It is not possible to create tmp files because of the amount of files. I want to do a db query.

Target: .net (C#)

Here are 2 pics for a better explanation.

[What I have](http://www6.pic-upload.de/16.02.11/8n49zom427vc.jpg)

[What I want](http://www6.pic-upload.de/16.02.11/f59i65c5vaa.jpg)

the 3 source of information come from a external source via database query.

regards Chris

Comment: your links are broken.. fix them first

Comment: your question is also not clear.. please provide more details.. do you want to search on internet or Local FileSystem

Comment: where I search is not so important. I want to provide the results with my own program. this program can search in internet and on a local server. I hoped that there is a interface in windows where I can provide my results. the image-links works for me...